# Sitecore search for users

Tags: content-search, user-profile

I've been doing some research on doing a search of the user base, using profile values for querying. I know there's a `sitecore_core_index` which in theory would cover that, but I'm guessing it's not that easy.

In looking around, the best I could find was this: https://gist.github.com/jorgelusar/150a607dcf96acb54b60. The associated blog that popped up in Google was no longer available, so this is all I have to work from. It looks like it would do the trick, and the code/config would just need to be modified for Solr (instead of Lucene).

My one concern is that right now, it appears to scan over the whole user base to do the indexing, so that it either has to be kicked off manually or run on a schedule. It'd be ideal if it could run when a user's information is added/updated.

If someone has ideas in that department, or knows of a more recent/modern (9.x) blog that discusses this subject, please point me (and all of us) in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

From core database are indexed just items. Sitecore users are stored in the memberhip table which doesn't appear like items on Core db.

You need to create your own crawler and your own index to index the users.

On this blogpost  is explained how to do it : https://nourestani.wordpress.com/2013/11/11/sitecore-lucene-net-how-to-index-users-and-profiles-from-core-database-part-1/ .

It's an old blogpost but it will point you to right direction.